# How to Display a progress bar whilst 'work' is 'working'

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a C# WPF Desktop app.

I want to do 'some 'work' and when I do I want to display a progress bar/info whilst waiting to complete.

So, to mock this up I have this UI:

```
<Window xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"  x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel x:Name="frm" Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Press Me!" />
            <Label Content="this is my test stuff"></Label>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="Hello Andy" x:Name="prog" Visibility="Collapsed"></TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My Code Behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void ShowBusy()
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
        new Action(() =>
        {
            frm.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            prog.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }));
}

private void HideBusy()
{


    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Send,
        new Action(() =>
        {
            frm.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            prog.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }));
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread th = new System.Threading.Thread(ShowBusy);
    th.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    HideBusy();
}
```

When I run this no 'Hello Andy' is displayed and the infinite loop just runs..

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115974/discussion-on-question-by-andrew-simpson-how-to-display-a-progress-bar-whilst-w).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread th = new Thread(DoSomething);
    th.Start();
}

private void DoSomething()
{
    ShowBusy();
    while (true)  // No Exit Clause ???
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    HideBusy();
}
```

Comment: hi, had not realized the Sleep blocked ALL threads. I replaced the infinite loop wait with a counter and it worked so thanks for that :)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson Sleep doesn't block all threads. It blocks the thread you call it on.

Comment: Never use BackgroundWorker before. I always use Thread (with IsBackground=true). Since .NET4, I change it to Task.Factory.StartNew (a threadpool) and better.

Comment: yes, I did start with Task.Run and switched to Threading and will now switch back to Task.Run without using my infinite route! I do not like BGW as I do no like the structure of it.  IT is very dated as well AFAIAK

Answer (score 1):

Async tasks have an `IProgress<T>` which allow you to know the progress of your long running methods.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IProgress<int> progress = new Progress<int>();
    progress.ProgressChanged += progress_ProgressChanged;

    await DoSomething(progress);
}

private void progress_ProgressChanged(object sender, int e)
{
    if(e < 100)
    {
        ShowBusy(e);  //Show busy with progress percentage
    }
    else
    {
        HideBusy();
    }
}

private async Task DoSomething(IProgress<int> progress)
{
    progress.Report(0)
    longMethod1();
    progress.Report(50)
    longMethod2();
    progress.Report(100)
}
```